# How to use cmake to organize libraries feature

Tags: build, cmake

In a project, there are many libraries:

- there are dependencies between libraries.
- each library has some features to enable/disable at build time.
- one library feature may depends on another library's specified feature.

Problem:

1. How to use cmake to organize such feature based dependency.
2. How to configure different target with different feature list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [option()](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aoption) and [set() with CACHE keyword](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aset) commands to define build options.

Use `if(OPTION_NAME)` to test for option value. Use `add_dependencies()` inside if block to make some of them optional.

Use [configure_file()](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aconfigure_file) to replace template file (config headerm for example) with options' values.